# Reduce the latency in live streaming from Android to red5

Tags: android, ffmpeg, streaming, red5, rtmp

I'm trying to find a way to reduce the latency while live streaming from android device to red5 media server.

I've used [this](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/), [this](https://code.google.com/p/android-rtmp-client/) and [this](https://github.com/mogo29/Android-RTMP)(Only audio) library to create my own test applications.
and I've used also an app found on play store.

The latency is always not less than 2-3 seconds.
Any suggestions how to reduce it?
Has anybody succeed in this?

I'm streaming within a LAN to the "oflaDemo" red5 demo app and viewing the stream with the "Publisher" red5 demo app.